# Grails Domain HQL Query

Tags: grails, hql

I have a grails domain named A. Like the following

```
Class A { 
    Integer x; 
    Collection<B> items 
}
```

and Class B is like the followings

```
Class B {
    Integer a;
    Integer b;
}
```

I need to find out sum of a*b group by x value of class a. For Example A class has rows having values x = 5, 6, 5; and some list of items.

I need two rows where i can find all the sum of items group by x means 5 and 6....  How can I do This. Thanks in advance..

*I need to do this with a single executequery like this **"select count(o.id), sum(o.items.a * o.items.b) from A as o group by a.x"** Is there any way i can do that like this....*

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def query = "FROM B AS b HAVING SUM(t.a * t.b) NOT NULL"
def result = A.findAll(query)
```

Comment: I need to use a single query like this.

"select count(a.id), sum(i.a * i.b) from A as a group by a.x"

is there any way i can do that like this...????

Comment: if you need to use the select phase, you need to have `withCriteria` and not HQL

Answer (score 0):

Try to this if this working:

```
def aList = A.createCriteria()
def result = aList.list() {
    projections {
        sum('a * b') != null
    }
}
```